# Why does my CSS width % change on certain pages?

Tags: css, width

On my website, the center elements are defined by width, 79%, and margin: auto.  I like how it looks.

But for some of the pages, the width and the margins are slightly different.  The page shifts slightly to the right and is slightly larger.  It's clear that the 79% width is calculated differently, and the margin: auto is as well.

I can't tell the difference between the pages, however.

See [this page](http://shobia.com/w/Watch_buying_guide) vs [this page](http://shobia.com/w/About).

I can’t figure out why.  Oddly, zooming in enough can make the difference disappear.

Here's some relevant css code:

```
#container,
#header,
#access,
#footer-wrap-inner,
.message
{   
    width: 79%; max-width: 80em; 
    margin: 0 auto; position: relative; 
}
```

The page does use ems to define some elements, but it doesn't seem relevant.

Input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the difference is the scrollbar appearing :) If I make the window so small that both of them have a vertical scrollbar, then no difference can be seen at all

Comment: btw: there is no real solution to that, it's a common disadvantage of centered layouts. I wouldn't suggest to always show a scrollbar. There are JS-Snippets that check for the scrollbar and move the container but well... it's quite overhead. And you don't just need to move but also to stretch it on every resize of the window.